# How to detect xss attack in Go and abort request with error

Tags: security, go, xss, go-gin

I am using **dvwright/xss-mw** middleware in Go to detect xss. This middleware auto remove xss from user submitted input, And request continue with valid response.
I want to detect xss and if there is any xss script then through a error instead of simply removing xss.

My code is here.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/dvwright/xss-mw"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    // include as standard middleware
    var xssMdlwr xss.XssMw
    r.Use(xssMdlwr.RemoveXss())

    r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "message": "pong",
        })
    })


    type Login struct {
        User     string `form:"user" json:"user" binding:"required"`
        Password string `form:"password" json:"password" binding:"required"`
    }

    r.POST("/login", func(c *gin.Context) {
        var json Login
        if c.BindJSON(&json) == nil {
            if json.User == "manu" && json.Password == "123" {
                c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"status": "you are logged in"})
            } else {
                c.JSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, gin.H{"status": "unauthorized"})
            }
        }
    })


    r.Run() // listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080
}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Detecting and removing XSS are both impossible. Instead, use strategies that are secure by default (automatic escaping, never disable escaping for individual cases if you can help it, never template inside `<script>` elements or unusual contexts like `on*` attributes) and create a restrictive Content-Security-Policy.

Comment: Thanks.
But when i call endpoint url  0.0.0.0:8080/login with POST and json data
as {
 "user" : "manu<script>prdknfkdngknfkint()</script>",
 "password" : "123"
 }
then output is 
{
  "status": "you are logged in"
}

I want to simply abort request instead of processing next, where this middleware is removing scripts.
For this where can i change code..

Comment: What’s the problem if someone submits that?

Comment: I don't want to store this malicious data in database. And i want to warn to user..
Thanks..

Comment: You want to warn the user submitting the XSS? Also, there’s no way to filter “malicious data” out of your database; just accept that it could end up there and plan accordingly.

Comment: How can i know if submitted data is malicious. And plan accordingly in future?

Comment: You *can’t* know if submitted data is malicious. Plan accordingly = don’t trust the user’s input. If you’re putting it in HTML, for example, make sure it’s always escaped.

Comment: i'm also looking to reject malicious requests. i've found node lib that does that here: https://github.com/akos-sereg/express-defend/blob/master/lib/express-defend.js?id=../../../etc/appsword